# Etcd v2 revision/version

Tags: version, response, revision, etcd

I have problem with `etcd` v2. I am creating configuration management which is using `etcd` v2 as K/V store. Now I do need version history as well but looks like v2 does not support it at least not straight out from the box.

I have been reading their API and at least v3 do have version/revision in response. Is there any way I could get version into v2 response as well?

Only solution currently I find is to use custom suffix with version numbers. Also using running number (`POST` instead of `PUT`) but looks like it is more as ID than version (every new or modified will increase that number)

Any ideas? Custom database to store previous versions only proper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that v2 does not support versions (feature in v3). I created own logic to handle versions.